# Configuring DWR?

Tags: java, javascript, dwr

I am new to DWR and want to implement a chat application and use DWR for that.

I followed [this turorial](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/) to configure it. I have put the war file in my webapps and started the server. I'm getting the classes when I used `http://localhost:8080/dwr/dwr/test/JavascriptChat`. How can I run this?

Comment: how can i set up to dun DWR chat?

Comment: DWR chat running in my server ? any suggestions

Comment: You need to ask a specific question + have some patience!

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured dwr.xml? Dont try to run the tutorials. Get the idea from the tutorial and try something simple and different than the tutorial. I used to waste lot of time in running the tutorial examples. But actually dwr is very easy to implement.

Also have a look at: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219636/java-dwr-passing-string/5310937#5310937)